# ошибка в коде c#

Tags: c#

пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку. как сделать так, чтобы выводились все описания?

```
public class movies
{
    #region св-ва(переменные) класса
    public string name_film; // св-ва класса или поля
    public string description;
    public string duration;

    public movies Filling(string name_film, string description, string duration)
    {
        movies mov = new movies();
        mov.name_film = name_film;
        mov.description = description;
        mov.duration = duration;

        return mov;
    }

    #endregion
}
class Program
{
    static void mood(movies f)
    {       

            Console.WriteLine("Название: {0} \r\nОписание: {1} \r\n Длительность:{2}", f.name_film, f.description, f.duration);            
    }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Добро пожаловать в приложение по подбору фильмов по настроению. Ваше настроение сегодня?(весёлое/грустное/воодушевленное/злое");
           string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            movies mov = new movies();
        if (answer == "весёлое")
        {
            mov = mov.Filling("Мачо и ботан", "Двое новоиспеченных горе-полицейских отправляются на сверхсекретное задание. Им предстоит заново стать учениками средней школы, в которой процветает наркоторговля.", "1 час 50 минут");
            mov = mov.Filling("Парни со стволами", "Реальная история о приятелях-планокурах из Майами, умудрившихся выбить в Пентагоне контракт на 300 миллионов долларов на поставку оружия.", "1 час 54 минуты");
            mov = mov.Filling("Волк с Уолл-стрит", "Джордан Белфорт основал одну из крупнейших брокерских контор в 1987 году, но десять лет спустя был осужден за отмывание денег и ряд прочих финансовых преступлений. ", "3 часа");
            mov = mov.Filling("Крутая Джорджия", "Увлекательный молодежный фильм расскажет вам о молодой юной красивой девушке", "1 час 53 минуты");
            mov = mov.Filling("Чарли и шоколадная фабрика", "Какие чудеса ждут вас на фабрике Вилли Вонки? Только представьте: травяные луга из сладкого мятного сахара в Шоколадной Комнате. .. Можно проплыть по Шоколадной реке на розовой сахарной лодке. .. Или поставить эксперименты в Комнате изобретений с леденцами", "1 час 55 минут");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 15);
            mood(mov);
        }
      else  if (answer == "грустное")
        {
            mov = mov.Filling("Побег из Шоушенка", "Шоушенк — название тюрьмы. И если тебе нет еще 30-ти, а ты получаешь пожизненное, то приготовься к худшему: для тебя выхода из Шоушенка не будет!", "2 часа 22 минуты");
            mov = mov.Filling("Леон", "Жесткий циничный киллер Леон ведет замкнутый и нелюдимый образ жизни. В свободное время мужчина занимается гимнастикой и ходит на мюзиклы .", "2 часа 13 минут");
            mov = mov.Filling("А зори здесь тихие", "Май 1942 года.В самый разгар Великой Отечественной Войны вдалеке от линии фронта, у забытого богом разъезда, фашисты выбрасывают десант с целью пробраться на Кировскую железную дорогу и Беломорско - Балтийский канал.Это не обычные солдаты - пехотинцы, это опытные, тренированные диверсанты, элита войск СС, «сверхлюди». А против них — старшина Васков и пятеро девчонок - зенитчиц.", "2 часа");
            mov = mov.Filling("12 лет рабства", "Соломон Нортап был женатым и образованным мужчиной, который жил и работал в Нью-Йорке, когда два человека однажды предложили ему привлекательную работу в Вашингтоне. По прибытии он был похищен, стал рабом и влачил жалкую жизнь, переходя от одного хозяина к другому.", "2 часа 14 минут");
            mov = mov.Filling("Одержимость", "Эндрю мечтает стать великим. Казалось бы, вот-вот его мечта осуществится. Юношу замечает настоящий гений, дирижер лучшего в стране оркестра. Желание Эндрю добиться успеха быстро становится одержимостью, а безжалостный наставник продолжает подталкивать его все дальше и дальше — за пределы человеческих возможностей.", "1 час 47 минут");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 15);
            mood(mov);
        }
      else  if(answer == "воодушевленное")
        {
            mov = mov.Filling("Интерстеллар", "Наше время на Земле подошло к концу, команда исследователей берет на себя самую важную миссию в истории человечества; путешествуя за пределами нашей галактики, чтобы узнать есть ли у человечества будущее среди звезд.", "2 часа 49 минут");
            mov = mov.Filling("Начало", "Кобб — талантливый вор, лучший из лучших в опасном искусстве извлечения: он крадет ценные секреты из глубин подсознания во время сна, когда человеческий разум наиболее уязвим", "2 часа 28 минут");
            mov = mov.Filling("Гравитация", "Доктор Райан Стоун, блестящий специалист в области медицинского инжиниринга, отправляется в свою первую космическую миссию под командованием ветерана астронавтики Мэтта Ковальски, для которого этот полет — последний перед отставкой. Но во время, казалось бы, рутинной работы за бортом случается катастрофа.", "1 час 31 минута");
            mov = mov.Filling("Звёздные войны: Пробуждение Силы", "Что бы ни говорили, но борьбе Света и Тьмы никогда не наступит конца, а значит, Звездные войны продолжаются!", "2 часа 18 минут");
            mov = mov.Filling("Тёмный рыцарь: Возрождение легенды", "Восемь лет назад Бэтмен растворился в ночи, превратившись из героя в беглеца. Приняв на себя вину за смерть прокурора Харви Дента, он пожертвовал всем. Вместе с комиссаром Гордоном они решили, что так будет лучше для всех. Пока преступность была раздавлена антикриминальным актом Дента, ложь действовала."," 2 часа 45 минут");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 15);
            mood(mov);
        }
      else  if (answer == "злое")
        {
            mov = mov.Filling("Злой"," Больше ста лет назад охотники на ведьм сожгли местную ведьму в её лесном доме Опен Харт.По преданию, ведьма выжила и мстит","1 час 45 минут");
            mov = mov.Filling("Зловещие мертвецы", "Молодые люди снимают на выходные загородный дом. Находится он в непролазной глуши, выглядит мрачно, а кругом — ни души. Аренда стоит копейки, но не потому, что он того и гляди развалится…","1 час 25 минут");
            mov = mov.Filling("Армия тьмы", "Фильм трилогии о книге темных магов, заклятия из которой пробуждают нечисть. "," 1 час 36 минут");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 15);
            mood(mov);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("ВЫ ВВЕЛИ НЕВЕРНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ!");

        Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: здесь можно и нужно по-русски задавать вопросы, да и лучше приводить какой тип эксепшена отображается, иначе не понятно

Comment: System.FormatException

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: уберите пробелы из `{ 0}` и т.д.

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva и что - FormatException? В какой строчке ошибка? Какое сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: В чем теперь вопрос? Ошибки-то больше нет.

Comment: Появляется только одно описание

Comment: Да одно, потому что Вы каждый раз перетираете переменную mov, вызывайте mood после каждого присваивания, или лучше создайте List<movies> (var moviesList = new List<movies>();), заполните его (moviesList.Add(mov);), потом выводите (moviesList.ForEach(mood); или через foreach). И сделайте метод Filling статическим, или переделайте в конструктор.

Comment: Ещё лучше сделать отдельный класс, который будет заниматься рекомендацией, с методом public List<movies> GetMoviesByMood(string mood) например, тогда вы сможете его переиспользовать в WinForms приложении.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Появляется необработанное исключение

Ошибка скорее всего тут:

```
Console.WriteLine("Название: { 0} \r\nОписание: { 1} \r\n Длительность:{ 2}", f.name_film, f.description, f.duration);
```

Много пробелов в описании параметра `{ 0}`. Попробуйте без пробела `{0}` (для всех параметров)

> как перевести эту программу в Windows forms

- Вынесите бизнес-логику в отдельный модуль
- Создайте Windows forms проект
- Добавьте модуль с бизнес-логикой в новый проект
- напишите код взаимодействия формы с бизнес-логикой

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы  выводилось не одно описание, а все?

Comment: mov = mov.Filling("Злой"," Больше ста лет назад охотники на ведьм сожгли местную ведьму в её лесном доме Опен Харт.По преданию, ведьма выжила и мстит","1 час 45 минут");
            mov = mov.Filling("Зловещие мертвецы", "Молодые люди снимают на выходные загородный дом. Находится он в непролазной глуши, выглядит мрачно, а кругом — ни души. Аренда стоит копейки, но не потому, что он того и гляди развалится…","1 час 25 минут"); mov = mov.Filling("Армия тьмы", "Фильм трилогии о книге темных магов, заклятия из которой пробуждают нечисть. "," 1 час 36 минут");

Comment: У Вас должен быть список из объектов mov. Сейчас передается только последний элемент, все остальные затираются. Потом список передать в mood и в цикле вывести результаты.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка здесь:

```
static void mood(movies f)
{


        Console.WriteLine("Название: {0} \r\nОписание: {1} \r\n Длительность:{2}", f.name_film, f.description, f.duration);


}
```

Уберите пробелы в фигурных скобках.

Comment: Пока писал ответ уже в комментариях @Igor ответил

Answer (score 1):

Каждый раз вызывая mov.Filling Вы перезапиваете переменные одного и того же экземпляра.
Вам нужно создать список или коллекцию экземпляров и потом добавлять туда новый экземпляр класса movies:

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Добро пожаловать в приложение по подбору фильмов по настроению. Ваше настроение сегодня?(весёлое/грустное/воодушевленное/злое");
  string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

  List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();

  Movie mov;
  if (answer == "весёлое")
  {
    mov = new Movie("Мачо и ботан", "Двое новоиспеченных горе-полицейских отправляются на сверхсекретное задание. Им предстоит заново стать учениками средней школы, в которой процветает наркоторговля.", "1 час 50 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Парни со стволами", "Реальная история о приятелях-планокурах из Майами, умудрившихся выбить в Пентагоне контракт на 300 миллионов долларов на поставку оружия.", "1 час 54 минуты");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Волк с Уолл-стрит", "Джордан Белфорт основал одну из крупнейших брокерских контор в 1987 году, но десять лет спустя был осужден за отмывание денег и ряд прочих финансовых преступлений. ", "3 часа");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Крутая Джорджия", "Увлекательный молодежный фильм расскажет вам о молодой юной красивой девушке", "1 час 53 минуты");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Чарли и шоколадная фабрика", "Какие чудеса ждут вас на фабрике Вилли Вонки? Только представьте: травяные луга из сладкого мятного сахара в Шоколадной Комнате. .. Можно проплыть по Шоколадной реке на розовой сахарной лодке. .. Или поставить эксперименты в Комнате изобретений с леденцами", "1 час 55 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 15);
    mood(movies);
  }
  else if (answer == "грустное")
  {
    mov = new Movie("Побег из Шоушенка", "Шоушенк — название тюрьмы. И если тебе нет еще 30-ти, а ты получаешь пожизненное, то приготовься к худшему: для тебя выхода из Шоушенка не будет!", "2 часа 22 минуты");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Леон", "Жесткий циничный киллер Леон ведет замкнутый и нелюдимый образ жизни. В свободное время мужчина занимается гимнастикой и ходит на мюзиклы .", "2 часа 13 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("А зори здесь тихие", "Май 1942 года.В самый разгар Великой Отечественной Войны вдалеке от линии фронта, у забытого богом разъезда, фашисты выбрасывают десант с целью пробраться на Кировскую железную дорогу и Беломорско - Балтийский канал.Это не обычные солдаты - пехотинцы, это опытные, тренированные диверсанты, элита войск СС, «сверхлюди». А против них — старшина Васков и пятеро девчонок - зенитчиц.", "2 часа");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("12 лет рабства", "Соломон Нортап был женатым и образованным мужчиной, который жил и работал в Нью-Йорке, когда два человека однажды предложили ему привлекательную работу в Вашингтоне. По прибытии он был похищен, стал рабом и влачил жалкую жизнь, переходя от одного хозяина к другому.", "2 часа 14 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Одержимость", "Эндрю мечтает стать великим. Казалось бы, вот-вот его мечта осуществится. Юношу замечает настоящий гений, дирижер лучшего в стране оркестра. Желание Эндрю добиться успеха быстро становится одержимостью, а безжалостный наставник продолжает подталкивать его все дальше и дальше — за пределы человеческих возможностей.", "1 час 47 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 15);
    mood(movies);
  }
  else if (answer == "воодушевленное")
  {
    mov = new Movie("Интерстеллар", "Наше время на Земле подошло к концу, команда исследователей берет на себя самую важную миссию в истории человечества; путешествуя за пределами нашей галактики, чтобы узнать есть ли у человечества будущее среди звезд.", "2 часа 49 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Начало", "Кобб — талантливый вор, лучший из лучших в опасном искусстве извлечения: он крадет ценные секреты из глубин подсознания во время сна, когда человеческий разум наиболее уязвим", "2 часа 28 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Гравитация", "Доктор Райан Стоун, блестящий специалист в области медицинского инжиниринга, отправляется в свою первую космическую миссию под командованием ветерана астронавтики Мэтта Ковальски, для которого этот полет — последний перед отставкой. Но во время, казалось бы, рутинной работы за бортом случается катастрофа.", "1 час 31 минута");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Звёздные войны: Пробуждение Силы", "Что бы ни говорили, но борьбе Света и Тьмы никогда не наступит конца, а значит, Звездные войны продолжаются!", "2 часа 18 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Тёмный рыцарь: Возрождение легенды", "Восемь лет назад Бэтмен растворился в ночи, превратившись из героя в беглеца. Приняв на себя вину за смерть прокурора Харви Дента, он пожертвовал всем. Вместе с комиссаром Гордоном они решили, что так будет лучше для всех. Пока преступность была раздавлена антикриминальным актом Дента, ложь действовала.", " 2 часа 45 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 15);
    mood(movies);
  }
  else if (answer == "злое")
  {
    mov = new Movie("Злой", " Больше ста лет назад охотники на ведьм сожгли местную ведьму в её лесном доме Опен Харт.По преданию, ведьма выжила и мстит", "1 час 45 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Зловещие мертвецы", "Молодые люди снимают на выходные загородный дом. Находится он в непролазной глуши, выглядит мрачно, а кругом — ни души. Аренда стоит копейки, но не потому, что он того и гляди развалится…", "1 час 25 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    mov = new Movie("Армия тьмы", "Фильм трилогии о книге темных магов, заклятия из которой пробуждают нечисть. ", " 1 час 36 минут");
    movies.Add(mov);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 15);
    mood(movies);
  }
  else
    Console.WriteLine("ВЫ ВВЕЛИ НЕВЕРНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ!");

  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Потом в методе mood в цикле выводе значение из каждого экземпляра:

```
  private static void mood(List<Movie> movies)
  {
   foreach (Movie f in movies)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Название: {0} \r\nОписание: {1} \r\n Длительность:{2}", f.Name, f.Description, f.Duration);
   }
  }
```

Я тут немного причесал Ваш класс:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Name; // св-ва класса или поля
    public string Description;
    public string Duration;

    public Movie(string name_film, string description, string duration)
    {
      this.Name = name_film;
      this.Description = description;
      this.Duration = duration;
    }
}
```